# How to intercept Linq filters

Tags: linq, filter, pipe

In LINQ to Objects, Is there anyway to identify which entities/objects qualified/disqualified at each filter?

For e.g) Let's say I have an entity called "Product' (Id , name) and if i input 100 Products into a Linq query which has 5 "where" conditon and get 20 Products as output.

Is there any way to identify which product got filtered at which where condition ?

Comment: Is it what you were looking for? (Also, it looks like you commented on your question instead of on my answer :P)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Various queries are in different places where I want to log such info.  Instead of making changes on multiple places is there any genralized approach to keep it in one place or with minimal changes

Comment: Well, I can think of a couple of ways to bend the language to your will: you *could* implement your own `Where` method and do logging from that method _but_ I would not as it is too much of a hack for my liking.

Comment: If an entity doesn't qualify for the first condition it may qualify for the next four, buy it never passes them. How do you deal with that?

Comment: If you want to log the data, then implement a standard logger, which takes IEnumerable<T> as input and logs, what ever you need to relevant place. In fact an extension method would be a good idea

Answer (score 2):

This can probably be generalized but you can do this.  I just don't see the use case for it.

Use `ToLookup()` to partition your queries.  The "disqualified" items would be lumped under the `false` group and you can continue your query with the `true` group.

e.g.,

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);
var p1 = numbers.ToLookup(n1 => n1 < 50); 
// p1[false] -> [ 50, 51, 52, ... ]
var p2 = p1[true].ToLookup(n2 => n2 % 2 == 0);
// p2[false] -> [ 1, 3, 5, 7, ... ]
var p3 = p2[true]... // and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

While everybody so far showed you how to do the obvious thing, i.e. group your data into chunks matching one condition, nobody addressed what you're actually asking

> identify which product got filtered *at which where condition*

The tough question is **how are going to log the where condition?**

It may seem trivial to do this, but you're going to fail because you won't be able to obtain a string representation of the `Func` object that was used. It is a delegate, i.e. compiled code, and you'll have to reverse-engineer it at runtime it to obtain the source code. This in itself is hard enough, but If the compiler chose to optimize the code you're lost.

Only if you're willing to create your own extension method(s) that use **expressions** in stead of `Func`s you'll be able to log the where condition, because an expression consists of tokens that can easily be 'ToString-ed' at runtime.

For instance:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereEx<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
{
    var logString = condition.Body.ToString();
    foreach (T item in sequence.Where(condition.Compile()))
    {
        yield return item;
        // logging hook here, this one simply dumps in Linqpad.
        string.Format("Item '{0}' meets '{1}'", item, logString).Dump();
    }
}
```

Now you're really intercepting the filter. But you have no clue where in the code the filter is applied. If you also want to log stack frames, performance will likely become an issue (reflection!), because it's already under pressure by compiling the expression each time. Then logging should be an async operation involving a thread-safe logging queue.